# Java change List item with ListIterator error

Tags: java, iterator

trying to modify a List under some condition with ListIterator, could anyone help me out?

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class TestIterator {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");
        list.add("C");
        System.out.println("List before modification: " + list);
        ListIterator<String> iterator = list.listIterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String element = iterator.next();
            if (element.equals("C")) {
                if (iterator.hasPrevious()) {
                    String previousElement = iterator.previous();
                    if (previousElement.equals("B")) {
                        iterator.set("BC");
                    }
                    iterator.next();
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("List before modification: " + list);
    }
}
```

expected output is:
List before modification: [A, B, C]
List after modification: [A, BC]

real output is:
List before modification: [A, B, C]
List before modification: [A, B]

Comment: As I ListIterator cannot write backward, and if your List Item is complex enough, ListIterator cannot even read backward.

Comment: Anyway, stepping through it with a debugger, `String previousElement = iterator.previous();` has a value of C which causes the following if statement to evaluate to false

Comment: what you should do is add in an extra iterator.previous() before your String previousElement and iterator.next() before iterator.remove().

Answer (score 2):

The iterator keeps 2 indexes. see private class java.util.ArrayList.Itr

```
int cursor;       // index of next element to return
int lastRet = -1; // index of last element returned; -1 if no such
```

After your condition `if (element.equals("C"))` has passed, the `cursor` is equal to 3, because that would be next element even though, there isn't 3rd element in that list. So by calling `iterator.hasPrevious()`, you are actually refering to index `cursor-1`, which is 2 and that is letter "C".
Then, when you called `iterator.previous()`, it actually returned element on index 2, which again is letter "C".
So in the end, you basically rewritten index 2 and then removed it's value.

To better understand what is going on, go over source code of ListIterator, it is kinda easy to understand, just go loop by loop and write down values if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you call `next`, and then `previous`, the list iterator will not have moved at all, and both calls will return the same element. You are just moving one position forward and then one backward, right?

Therefore, in this part of the code:

```
if (element.equals("C")) {
    if (iterator.hasPrevious()) {
        String previousElement = iterator.previous();
        if (previousElement.equals("B")) {
```

The `previous` call will return the same thing as the `next` call on the first line, so `previousElement` will always be equal to `element`. Since `element` is "C", it can't be "B", and the innermost if statement will never be run.

You should call `previous` and extra time

```
if (element.equals("C")) {
    iterator.previous(); // <--- here!
    if (iterator.hasPrevious()) {
        String previousElement = iterator.previous();
        if (previousElement.equals("B")) {
```

This is always safe to call because you just called `next` 2 lines before. Going back is always safe, since you are just going back to where you came from.

Similarly, after the `if (previousElement.equals("B"))` statement, you also need to call `next` an extra time:

```
}
iterator.next();
iterator.next();
iterator.remove();
```

By counting the number of times `next` and `previous` called before this point, you can see that both of these `next`s are safe.

Note that this would end up in an infinite loop if the list starts with "C". You can call `next` in the `else` block of `if (iterator.hasPrevious())` to prevent this.

Comment: @experimentunit1998X Yeah, the docs even say "Note that alternating calls to next and previous will return the same element repeatedly."

Comment: yes, but i was confused why the docs said that, so i went to check the debugger again

Answer (score 0):

nb: Not quite sure what you are doing with the sequence.

```
 int count=0;
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
        
        String element = iterator.next();
                    if (element.equals("C")) {
                        if (iterator.hasPrevious()) {
                            String previousElement = iterator.previous();
                            if (previousElement.equals("B")) {
            list.set((count-1),"BC");
count-=1;
                            }
      iterator.next(); // not sure what's happening in the sequence with this
                            iterator.remove();
        count++;
        }
```

It may be better to search with list.indexOf  or list.lastIndexOf , list.size , list.get